# Selecting between two timestamps returns no data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two unix timestamps 65 seconds apart and i am trying to query mysql in this manner

This is 65 seconds apart `1504684252 + 65`

> SELECT ask FROM live_rates WHERE  `the_time` BETWEEN
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1504684252) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1504684317)
>
> SELECT ask FROM live_rates WHERE  `the_time` BETWEEN
>   FROM_UNIXTIME(1504684252) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1504684317)

In my table, there is an event starting at timestamp `1504684252` and ending 65 seconds later. Why is there no data returned by either of the queries?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make it clear what data type `the_time` is - if it's a unix timestamp (i.e. an integer) already, just query it as an integer, given that you seem to know the unix timestamps of your date range:

```
SELECT ask FROM live_rates WHERE  the_time BETWEEN 1504684252 AND 1504684317
```

If your data in `the_time` is stored as a datetime, I'd say you should make sure that the server really is converting the values you've supplied to a datetime range that includes the relevant record:

```
SELECT ask FROM live_rates WHERE id = abcdef

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1504684252), FROM_UNIXTIME(1504684317)
```

Run these two queries (with the id replaced) and eyeball the data. You'll find the reason, I'm sure  - possibly something like a timezone issue, and your unix timestamps are translating to some time in UTC whereas your table data is showing some other time and you've hence mis-translated the time shown into a unix time.. Or possibly that it's an end date that has some time component outside the range of the unix times you specified even though the date part of it is correct.

It's hard to say for sure without a complete, verifiable example (a create table statement with inserted test data and a select demonstrating the problem. Try sqlfiddle.com)

ps; Don't use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in the way you wrote here; it's not intended to have a unix timestamp passed into it. You either pass it no arguments (in which case it gives you the current datetime of the server clock, as a unix timestamp) or you pass it some datetime (and it will return you the equivalent unix timestamp of that datetime)

Answer (score 0):

If `the_time` is a unix timestamp as opposed to a date i.e. `1504684252` instead of `2017-09-01 00:00:00`, then you don't need `FROM_UNIXTIME`, which converts a unix timestamp to a date:

```
SELECT ask FROM live_rates WHERE the_time BETWEEN 1504684252 AND 1504684317
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP` takes a date/time as parameter and returns an integer. When you're feeding it with an integer it returns 0 - so you're selecting between 0 and 0.

`FROM_UNIXTIME` takes an integer but it returns a date/time - so if `the_time` is an integer they're not compatible.